# How to import method-wrapper type?

Tags: python, methods, types, inspect

I have a library [module-wrapper](https://github.com/rominf/module-wrapper/) that recursively wraps objects. I want to determine if an object has a function-like type. I can check almost all function-like object using:

```python
inspect.isbuiltin(object=obj) or
inspect.isfunction(object=obj) or
inspect.ismethod(object=obj) or
inspect.ismethoddescriptor(object=obj)
```

The problem is that some bound methods are not detected with this code, for example:

```python
s = "Hello, world!"
type(s.__add__)
# method-wrapper
```

I guess I cannot check objects for being `method-wrapper` using `inspect` module. But how do I import this type? I didn't find it.

Now I have an ugly hack in my code:

```python
MethodWrapper = type(''.__add__)
isinstance(obj, MethodWrapper)
```

**UPD0:**

I don't want to use `callable` because it detects classes and objects, that implement `__call__`, but I want those classes and objects to be handled separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `types` module provides names for many “implementation” types, including several for functions implemented in C.  The specific example of `type("".__str__)`, `MethodWrapperType`, was just added in CPython 3.7.

Because this area is subtle and the number of types is large, `callable` may really be the best choice.  You can easily check for `type` objects first to “exclude” classes, and various heuristics (*e.g.*, `try`ing to call `vars` on an object or examining `type(x).__module__`) can be used to recognize typical “callable objects” (not that those are fundamentally different from the built-in function types).

Comment: I didn't find anything in the `types` module.
I don't want to use `callable` because it detects classes and objects, that implement `__call__`, but I want those classes and objects to be handled separately.

Comment: It [seems](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ROJ5hVWHhtbYSY21) to handle your `"".__add__` case just fine (but that name was added only in 3.7).  If you want to treat classes differently, just check for them first; `vars` might help with the mostly-arbitrary distinction between "raw functions" and "user-level callable objects".

Comment: Davis, can you please edit your answer so that I could upvote it (I downvoted it because I didn't find anything in the `types` module of Python 3.6).

Comment: @rominf: Integrating the comments is a good idea and has been done—not that anything forced you to downvote at the *same time* as asking about an apparent inconsistency (and editing your question).

Comment: Davis sorry, I didn't get the point about callable objects. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Davis, by some reason if I use `@` to mention you I get nothing in the output instead of mentioning you. It's strange. I think it's SO bug.

Comment: @rominf: As it’s my answer, I get notified regardless; I think it strips the mention for brevity.

Comment: @rominf: It’s something of a philosophical question as yo whether an object that provides `__call__` *is* a function or merely *acts* like one.  It’s even possible to have an object of a `class` type that invokes a C-defined function when called (with **no** `def __call__(self):` intermediary).